How to Generate a .bin File Without TouchGFX Images in STM32 Firmware?
I am working on firmware development using STM32CubeIDE with TouchGFX for an STM32H750Bx MCU. The firmware includes a GUI and a CAN-Bus for external communication.
Currently, the firmware size is around 6 MB, with approximately 5.75 MB being dedicated to graphics (TouchGFX images), which are stored in an external W25Q128 flash memory.
I developed a custom tool to flash new firmware updates, primarily for adding features or fixing bugs. However, this tool is not optimized for handling large files, and flashing the current firmware with the GUI takes about 4 hours, which is impractical.
In the linker file (.ld), I separated the memory regions:
Firmware: Stored in external flash starting at 0x90000000, size 4 MB.
Images: Stored in external flash starting at 0x90400000, size 12 MB.
The images (TouchGFX assets) are rarely changed and are the same across updates. I want to flash only the firmware without reloading the images.
My question is, Is it possible to generate a .bin file that excludes the TouchGFX images, so I can flash only the updated firmware?
I was thinking of saving those images to specific memory addresses and accessing them from the main firmware, however, I am not sure how could I do this. Would it be necessary to generate a .bin just for the images, apart from the main firmware?
Any clarification would be very welcomed.

I presume that the last step of your build is to run arm-none-eabi-objcopy from ELF to bin or hex.  This is probably in the post-build script of the eclipse project.
All you need to do is add the option --remove-section= with an argument matching what is in your linker script.  See the manpage for details.
You can run objcopy multiple times to create output files with/without/with only the data part.
